# Selenium java 3.141.59 - WebDriver and FirefoxDriver issue

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have set java jre jdk and set its paths (env)
I have installed eclipse 
I have downloaded the Mozilla Gecko Driver and set its path (env)
I have downloaded the selenium java 3.141.59
I have added the available jars from the above into my eclipse project (external jars)

Then I have the errors;

```
Can not find WebDriver
Can not find FirefoxDriver
```

Just can’t see what am doing wrong.

Comment: You should provide more information such as your code and detailed error message so that people can help you better.Can you write the code as `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\browser_driver\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");` before you create a chromeDriver?

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an issue with selenium dependency **3.141.59**, it **does not finds FirefoxDriver()** to initialize.
I used slightly lesser version **3.141.5** which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your project is not able to read your external jars(Selenium Jars) and hence you are getting errors like these.

Probable Solutions:

1. Remove and add the latest version of selenium jar files again.
2. Use Dependency management tool like Maven, which will pull the required version of selenium jars on your local machine based on the configuration provided in the POM.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You should download firefox exe file and need to set property as shown below

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\geckodriver-v0.20.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("passurl");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
```